# How many visas are required to visit Kazakhstan (from India)?

Tags: visas, international-travel, kazakhstan

So my friend who lives in Kazakhstan(originally from there) says it will take me three visas- Schengen  visa ,Kazakhstan visa and Russian Visa. But I doubt that. Please help me out here.

Comment: Why do you need a Schengen visa or a Russian visa if you are going to Kazakhstan?

Comment: See I've no idea about that... my friend said so. So that's why I am asking for some help here.

Comment: What did your friend say when you asked him the above question?

Comment: Well after googling a lot about it, even I was not able to find any such necessity to have 3 visas. And so did I asked him back this thing in Facebook. Well he hasn't replied yet. Well he don't use fb quite frequently but I am sure he will reply soon. Well in meantime I thought to ask this here. So here I am.

Comment: This is nonsense.  Someone may need a Schengen to transit the Schengen zone or a Russian transit in order to arrive in Kazakhstan, but it's lunacy to think Kazakhstan requires three visas.  Close voting as 'unclear'.

Comment: It's not unclear at all. He wants to know what visas he needs. The only unclear part is his friend's concept of visas.

Comment: @MarkMayo, we need more choices for close reasons.  'Unclear' is not perfect, but a close enough match for 'silly' :)

Comment: @AmitAmola: Travelling overland to Kazakhstan from India? That would make this question make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Wiki entry of visa requirements for Indian citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens), a visa is indeed required for Kazakhstan.  However, only Kazakhstan.

It redirects you to an [information page on timaticweb](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KZ&user=EK&subuser=EMIRATES):

```
Visa Issuance:
- Visitors arriving from a country without Kazakh
  representation and holding an invitation letter, can obtain

  a single entry visa on arrival for a max. stay of 1 month if
  visa is pre-arranged by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs.
  Fee: approx. USD 80.-. Applicable only at Aktau (SCO),
  Almaty (ALA), Astana (TSE), Atyrau (GUW) and Uralsk (URA).
Additional Information:

- Visitors staying for more than 5 days must register at the
  OVIR office. 
Warning:
- Visitors who are visa exempt but do not hold return/onward
  tickets could be refused entry.
```

So the only weirdness there is that it does depend on which airport you fly into, but assuming you're using one of the main ones, you should be fine there.

For further information, we defer to the [Kazakh embassy in India](http://www.kazakhembassy.in/):

Here you can find the actual form for [a visa application to Kazakhstan for Indian citizens](http://www-pub.iaea.org/mtcd/meetings/PDFplus/2009/cn172/cn172_VisaForm.pdf).  Note that nowhere on it does it require any other visas.

**Short version** - aside from a visa for Kazakhstan, no further visas are required, UNLESS you're going to other countries before Kazakhstan, in which case you'll need visas for those countries, if required.

Comment: The timatic web link now shows "No Access"

Answer (score 5):

If there're direct flights to Kazakhstan from India, i don't see any reason you should have any other country's visa. 
Also, Kazakhstan embassy in New Delhi has a direct phone number listed over their website http://www.kazakhembassy.in/

I hope it helps.